# AutoHotkey displays MsgBox before assignment to variable

Tags: autohotkey

This is my first AHK script and I'm having trouble getting it to do what I want. Using the key combination Ctrl+Alt+A in Notepad, I want to jump to the beginning of a line of text, select the first character, copy it to the clipboard, and check what letter it is. Right now, I'm just trying to check the contents of the clipboard using a `MsgBox` but there's a problem: the `MsgBox` displays it's contents **before** the copy command! Here's the script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad

^!a::
    Send, {Home}
    Send, {LShift Down}{Right}{LShift Up}
    Send, ^c
    MsgBox, %clipboard%
return
```

Running the command multiple times, you will see that it copies the selected text **after** it displays the `MsgBox`. It displays the text from the previous command. Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

**Update:** It would seem that the little piece of script that I neglected to include in the question might be the culprit: `SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.` I've updated the script above also. When I remove that line, it works as expected. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Your code works perfectly fine for me. --- two minor hints: hotkeys, hotstrings and labels should always terminate with a `return`. Add this at the very bottom of your code. --- `#ifWinActive, ahk_class Notepad` starts the beginning of a notepad-only-hotkey-section. You might want to close it with `#ifWinActive` at the very very bottom at the code.

Comment: You could, however, add `keyWait, {ctrl}` after the `send ^c`, or make use of the `setkeydelay` keyword

Comment: Thank you guys, I've added the `return` keyword to the end of the script but that actually wasn't the problem. I neglected to include the boiler plate code that was generated when I created the script. This statement: `SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.` seems to be the culprit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The removal of `SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.` rectified the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it simply that you've not added the `return,` line to the end of the code?

```
^!a::
    Send, {Home}
    Send, {LShift Down}{Right}{LShift Up}
    Send, ^c
    MsgBox, %clipboard%
return,
```

alternatively you could add a delay, the command for this is `sleep`, 1000 = 1 second.

If it fails, try this:

```
^!a::
    Send, {Home}
    Send, {LShift Down}{Right}{LShift Up}
    Send, ^c
    sleep, 200
    MsgBox, %clipboard%
return,
```